# global variable doesnot work in another function why

Tags: php

**MY dbMySql.PHP FILE CODING**

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS' ,'');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbtuts');

class DB_con
{
 function __construct()
 {
 global $conn;
 $conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die('localhost connection problem'.mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
 }
 public function insert($fname,$lname,$city)
 {
  $sql = "INSERT users(first_name,last_name,user_city)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$city')";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  return $res;
 }
 public function select()
 {
    // $db=new DB_con();
   //  $db->__construct();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
   $res=mysql_query($sql);

    // return $conn;
   return $res;
 }
}
?>
```

**MY index.php FILE**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbMySql.php';
$con = new DB_con();
$table = "users";
$res=$con->select($table);
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="header">
 <div id="content">
    <label></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="body">
 <div id="content">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="3"><a href="add_data.php">ADD</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
 while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
 {
   ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
 <div id="content">
    <hr /><br/>
    <label>Appxone Private Limited<a href="http://cleartuts.blogspot.com"></a></label>
    </div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**MY add_data.php FILE CODING**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbMySql.php';
$con = new DB_con();

// data insert code starts here.
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{
 $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
 $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
 $city = $_POST['city_name'];

 $res=$con->insert($fname,$lname,$city);
 if($res)
 {
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('Record inserted...');
        window.location='index.php'
  </script>
  <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('error inserting record...');
        window.location='index.php'
        </script>
  <?php
 }
}
// data insert code ends here.

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Data Insert and Select Data Using OOP - By Cleartuts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id="header">
 <div id="content">
    <label>PHP Data Insert and Select Data Using OOP - By Cleartuts</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="body">
 <div id="content">
    <form method="post">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="city_name" placeholder="City" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <button type="submit" name="btn-save"><strong>SAVE</strong></button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**MY style.css Coding is**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#header
{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background:#00a2d1;
 color:#f9f9f9;
 font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size:35px;
 text-align:center;
}
#header a
{
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration:blink;
}
#body
{
 margin-top:50px;
}
table
{
 width:40%;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bolder;
 color:#999;
 margin-bottom:80px;
}
table a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#00a2d1;
}
table,td,th
{
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border:solid #d0d0d0 1px;
 padding:20px;
}
table td input
{
 width:97%;
 height:35px;
 border:dashed #00a2d1 1px;
 padding-left:15px;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 0px rgba(1,0,0,0.2);
 outline:none;
}
table td input:focus
{
 box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(1,0,0,0.2);
 outline:none;
}
table td button
{
 border:solid #f9f9f9 0px;
 box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(1,0,0,0.2);
 outline:none;
 background:#00a2d1;
 padding:9px 15px 9px 15px;
 color:#f9f9f9;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bolder;
 border-radius:3px;
 width:100%;
}
table td button:active
{
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
#footer
{
 margin-top:50px;
 position:relative;
 bottom:30px;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

all code is working and data insert successfully and show but if you see above first file i am using mysql,i want to use mysqli but issue is that when show $conn as a global variable (because mysqli needed 2 parameters) and use in mysqli($sql,$conn),error show undefined variable $conn why?

Comment: Define the variable outside the function and it should work?

Comment: $conn global variable make in function but when use in another function doesnot work why eror undefined see only my first file and last wordings then you understand my problem

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Don't use the [`mysql_*()` PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) in new code. They are old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4265352) to learn more about why and how.

Comment: You have to declare what variables are global on the scope of every function that uses them. If you want your method `select()` to have access to global variable `$conn`, you have to add `global $conn` in there too.

Comment: Read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: tell me how i can use $conn in another function with mysqli because when i am using give me error undefined

Comment: Just put `global $conn` on every function that uses `$conn`. Also, MySQLi introduces object oriented support, you can use `$conn->query($sql)`  instead of `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make `$conn` a property of your object instead of making it a global variable. Set and use `$this->conn`.

Comment: Also use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) too, to protect yourself from SQL injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $this for access variables in your class

```
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS' ,'');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbtuts');

class DB_con {
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die('localhost connection problem'.mysql_error());
        mysqli_select_db($this->conn, DB_NAME);
    }
    public function insert($fname,$lname,$city) {
        $sql = "INSERT users(first_name,last_name,user_city)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$city')";
        $res = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        return $res;
    }
    public function select() {
        // $db=new DB_con();
        //  $db->__construct();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $res = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);

        // return $conn;
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Almog i am using your code but error show in second last line,  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: @AllWorld I edited my code, B.Desai thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @AllWorld `while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res))`. You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`. Also, both this and your `select` function don't accept any parameters but you pass in the table in your code